# Looking for a specific BibTeX style

Tags: bibtex, formatting

I am brand new to BibTeX, so I apologize if this question is painfully naive.  Up until now, I have been manually creating my bibliography for each paper using the environment `thebibliography`.  I'm now in the process of creating a master .bib file that holds all of the citations that I will ever use.  However, I'm having a problem getting my bibliography to *look* the way that I'd like.

How can I get the entry

```
@article {EnoJen95,
    author = {Enochs, Edgar E. and Jenda, Overtoun M. G.},
     title = {Gorenstein injective and projective modules},
   journal = {Math. Z.},
  fjournal = {Mathematische Zeitschrift},
    volume = {220},
      year = {1995},
    number = {4},
     pages = {611--633},
}
```

to be printed in the same way that the following would render:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{EnoJen95} E.~E.~Enochs and O.~M.~G.~Jenda, 
  \emph{Gorenstein injective and projective modules}, 
  Math.~Z. \textbf{220}(4) (1995), 611--633.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

So, basically, the output should look like:

[1]  E. E. Enochs and O. M. G. Jenda, *Gorenstein injective and projective modules*, Math. Z. **220**(4) (1995), 611-633.

Any help would be appreciated...even if someone could steer me in the direction of a good resource for BibTeX styles.

Comment: As Alan Munn mentions in his answer, the question is underspecified. Should the bibliography be in alphabetic order by first author's surname? or should the bibliography be in order of mention? What about the styling for books, book chapters and so on?

Comment: @Seamus I know that I didn't specify the style for other types of references, but I was looking specifically for this type.  Alan's suggestion of using the `amsrefs` package ended up fixing the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are just starting out using `bibtex` and you really need to make your own style, I would strongly recommend starting out with the `biblatex` package rather than the standard `natbib` package, since it provides fairly easy ways to customize almost any bibliography style you need using LaTeX methods rather than the rather obscure `.bst` file language.

BUT, before you start constructing your own, you should be aware that it's not a simple task: you've only specified the form for a *single* reference type, but there are many others (books, papers in books, theses, etc.), so it's really a better idea to use a style that is already established (perhaps from a journal in your field, (or the AMS, since it looks like you are a mathematician. If that's the case, there is also the `amsrefs` package, which should be part of your TeX distribution, and is a substitute for the `natbib`+`bibtex` route.))

Furthermore, in addition to the style of your references, there is also the style of the citations in your text, and again, there are a variety of different types.  So you really don't want to re-invent the wheel, especially if you don't really know all of the possibilities that might arise.

If you want to keep with `natbib`+`bibtex` there are a number of pre-made `.bst` files.  Search on [CTAN's directory of `.bst` files](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/) or search [here](http://bst.maururu.net/). You can also use the `makebst` program (`latex makebst`) which will step you through a bunch of questions to construct your own.

Comment: I ended up using the `amsrefs` package with the `abbrev` option, and it worked perfectly...thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Consider making your Bibliography Style file own by running:

`latex makebst`

from the command-line. It'll ask you a number of multiple choice questions about how to structure the bibliography, and produce a .bst file at the end of the process. You can certainly recreate what you're asking for here. (Though there are many other choices you'll have to make.)

Consider looking into BibLaTeX as well.